# Jenkins plugin for triggering build from Dashboard with input argument?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a project with more than 100k regression tests and therefore we'd like to have the alternative to manually trigger and check if a Test Suite(s) have been broken due to a specific change instead of running all tests.

I have a build project configured in a way that everything is in place and it expects only parameter value to be appended i.e. `-DwildcardSuites=<Suite Name Pattern>`.

Is there a Jenkins plugin that would allow entering an input text to be appended to the `Goals and options` and that corresponds to the specific Suite pattern we'd like to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensible Choice? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin

There are a few similar plugins, they tend to have one or more of "Choice", "Active" and "Dynamic" in the name.